# How to install package to a specific path contains a spece

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to install python package to a specific path. the problem is that path contains space as follows:

```
m:\ pip install --target=m:\s\a b\ package_name
```

the package will not be installed in the designated path because the path contains space separating a nd b
please let me know how to solve this issue

Comment: try adding `""` like `pip install "some package"`

Answer (score 0):

```
m:\ pip install package_name --target="m:\s\a b\package_name"
```

This works on Windows machine.